# Search the field value contains &#x27; in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a bunch of values with `&#x27;` in the `nam` field. I want to retrieve those specifically from the other.

For example :

- `O'Corner` saved in my DB as `O&#x27;Corner`
- `O'Miller` saved in my DB as `O&#x27;Miller`

How can I fetch these records specifically?

Comment: Depends on RDBMS... `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE nam LIKE '%''%'`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the problem?

When using the SQL Console, you should escape those characters:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  nam = 'O\'Miller'
```